# Test new Dedicated Internet Access line

Tags: lan, wan

Our provider has just installed a EdgeCore switch/router in our office and I would like to test out the speed with my laptop. Here's what I'm provided

1) a range of LAN IP address/subnet
2) WAN IP address/subnet
3) DNS IPs

How do I go about testing the Internet connection with just my laptop alone? I thought I just want to verify the connection speed before I ask our vendor to configure our firewall and the other switches.

Comment: What type of internet? How is it terminated

Comment: It is leased line Dedicated Internet Access (DIA) circuit. The termination device is an EdgeCore es3510ma.

Comment: What does hinder you from evaluating using any of these? --> https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=internet+connection+speed+test

Comment: I know how to run the test itself. The thing is when I plug in my laptop to the device, I am not getting any Internet access. I'm sure I need to configure something on my laptop like the IP address before I can get anything.

Comment: You need as a minimum to get DHCP and the external gateway configured on the EdgeCore switch/router. Otherwise nothing will have internet access. You should be asking the provider to at least set up a working internet before thinking about testing and configuring other devices on your network.

Comment: I thought I could just assign an IP on my laptop itself and get my Internet tested. Well according to the provider, the internet is activated and working already on port number 1. So I've assigned my laptop one of the LAN ips given but nothing is working. I'm also confused what should be the default gateway.